# AddThis share plugin conflict with flash(not showing) in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, flash, addthis

On my page here:
http://metallica-gr.net/mp3/mp3.html

On the middle of the screen there is a flash mp3 player. It appears on every browser except IE9 which for some reason conflicts with the AddThis share plugin script. If I remove the script below(which obviously makes the plugin to not work), the flash content appears fine.
Any idea why this happens in IE9 and how I can fix it?

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div align="center" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" id="addthis" style="float:none; padding-bottom:10px;">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:layout="button_count" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
<div id="share"><a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a></div>
</div><br/><br/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5079327f7265b166"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the script on the head section instead fixed the issue on IE9.